# Alternative to multiprocessing.map that won't store the returning values of functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using `multiprocessing.imap_unordered` to run a function concurrently but my RAM usage keeps increasing.

The problem is the following: I have millions of combinations (created with `itertools.product`) of data that need to be passed to a function. That function will then use an SVM to calculate a score and then store the score and the current combination. **This function won't return any value** it will only calculate a score and store it in a shared value. I don't need all the other combinations but the best only.

By using `imap_unordered` the RAM usage keeps increasing until it crashes by lack of RAM. I suppose this happens because the `imap` will store the result of the functions, that won't return any value but will possibly keep a `None` or `Null` value?

Here is an example code:

```
from functools import partial
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import time


def svm(input_data, params):

    # Copy the data to avoid changing the original data
    # as input_data is a reference to a pandas dataframe
    # and I need to shift columns up and down.
    dataset = input_data.copy()

    # Use svm here to analyse data
    score = sum(dataset) + sum(params)  # simulate score of svm

    # Simulate a process that takes a bit of time
    time.sleep(0.5)

    return (score, params)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Without this, multiprocessing gives error
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    # Set the number of worker processes
    # Empty for all the cores
    # Int for number of processes
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    # iterable settings
    total_combinations = 2
    total_features = 45

    # Keep track of best score
    best_score = -1000
    best_param = [0 for _ in range(total_features)]

    input_data = [x * x for x in range(10000)]

    # Create a partial function with the necessary args
    func = partial(svm, input_data)
    params = itertools.product(range(total_combinations), repeat=total_features)

    # Calculate scores concurrently
    # As the iterable is in the order of millions, this value
    # will get continuously large until it uses all available
    # memory as the map stores the results, that in this case
    # it's not needed.
    for score, param in pool.imap_unordered(func, iterable=params, chunksize=100):
        if score > best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_param = param

    # Wait for all the processes to terminate their tasks
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(best_score)
    print(best_param)
```

In this example, you will notice that the RAM usage increases over time. Although in this case it is not much, if you leave alone for a day or something (by increasing the range of the iterable) it will reach GBs of RAM. As I have said, I have millions of combinations.

How should I fix this issue? Are there alternatives to `imap` that simply won't store anything about the function? Should I just create `Processes` instead of using a `Pool`? Could it be because I'm copying the dataset and later it is not cleaned up by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've traced the memory usage with `import objgraph` and printing `objgraph.show_most_common_types(limit=20)`. I noticed that the number of tuples and lists kept increasing for the duration of the child processes. To solve this issue, I've changed the `maxtasksperchild` in the `Pool` to forcefully close the processes after some time and consequentially free the memory.

```
from functools import partial
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

# Tracing memory leaks
import objgraph


def svm(input_data, params):

    # Copy the data to avoid changing the original data
    # as input_data is a reference to a pandas dataframe.
    dataset = input_data.copy()

    # Use svm here to analyse data
    score = sum(dataset) + sum(params)  # simulate score of svm

    # Simulate a process that takes a bit of time
    time.sleep(0.5)

    return (score, params)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # iterable settings
    total_combinations = 2
    total_features = 12

    # Keep track of best score
    best_score = -1000
    best_param = [0 for _ in range(total_features)]

    # Simulate a dataframe with random data
    input_data = [random.random() for _ in range(100000)]

    # Create a partial function with the necessary args
    func = partial(svm, input_data)
    params = itertools.product(range(total_combinations), repeat=total_features)

    # Without this, multiprocessing gives error
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    # Set the number of worker processes
    # Empty for all the cores
    # Int for number of processes
    with multiprocessing.Pool(maxtasksperchild=5) as pool:

        # Calculate scores concurrently
        # As the iterable is in the order of millions, this value
        # will get continuously large until it uses all available
        # memory as the map stores the results, that in this case
        # it's not needed.
        for score, param in pool.imap_unordered(func, iterable=params, chunksize=10):
            if score > best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_param = param
                # print(best_score)

            # Count the number of objects in the memory
            # If the number of objects keep increasing, it's a memory leak
            print(objgraph.show_most_common_types(limit=20))

    # Wait for all the processes to terminate their tasks
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(best_score)
    print(best_param)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply) or [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async)

Comment: From what I'm reading, it doesn't seem that `apply` will use an iterable. What I mean with this is that it will try to evaluate the whole list instead of lazy loading. This will be a problem as my iterable list is too large.

Comment: I'll try to explain myself. 

You can iterate over all params `for param in params:` and then apply them to the pool `pool.apply_async(func=your_func, args=(param,))`. 

You can also use the callback param to filter out the best scores `def callback_func(score, params): if score > best_score: ......`. You should use also a lock inside the callback function to avoid problems when assigning best_score and best_params

Comment: Instead of locks I can use a `manager.Value` and keep the best score. This solution works. Another solution I've tried is to just set the `maxtasksperchild` in the `Pool` as it will close the process and open a new one.